# D3 update line graph

Tags: csv, d3.js

I created a line graph using a csv file and now I am trying to update this graph using new data from the same csv. However when I open the file in firefox I am getting an error: ReferenceError: updateData is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="option">
            <input name="updateButton" 
             type="button" 
            value="Update" 
            onclick="updateData()" />
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
       var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 150},
       width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

       // Set the ranges
       var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
       var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

      // Define the axes
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
          .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"))
          .orient("bottom");

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(5);

      // Define the line
      var valueline = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.AttendancePerG); });

      // Adds the svg canvas
      var svg = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", 
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");           

      // Get the data
      d3.csv("piratesAttendance.csv", function(error, data) {
           data.forEach(function(d) {
                  d.Year = +d.Year;
                  d.AttendancePerG = +d.AttendancePerG;
      });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.AttendancePerG; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width",2)
        .attr("fill","none");

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.tsv("pittsburghAttendance", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Year = +d.Year;
            d.Attendance = +d.Attendance;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Attendance; })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    // Make the changes
    svg.select(".line")   // change the line
        .duration(750)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxis);

        });
     }                                                          
     });

      </script>

      </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `updateData` is defined in a callback, so it will not be in the "global" scope of your page, hence you cannot invoke it from the HTML.

Try to simply move its declaration to the beginning (or end) of your `<script>` tag.

Oh and also your usage of `d3.csv` seems incorrect.

Comment: Moving the updateData() function to the end of the script tag results in a different error: NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied. Which part of the d3.csv is incorrect?